# Raw query inside entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I am making a twitter clone.

The join table creates a `following` table with a `user_id` and `follower_id`

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
@JoinTable(
        name = "following",
        joinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))],
        inverseJoinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "follower_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))]
)
var following: List<User> = emptyList()
```

The following query gives me my followers

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT user_id FROM following WHERE `follower_id` = 1)
```

How can I implement this query in my entity?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into the mappedBy attribute on ManyToMany. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html
You can add an additional field to your entity class that should accomplish what you're looking for.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "following")
var followers: List<User> = emptyList()
```